Content-Security-Policy violated in jquery.min.js and SessionExpire.js
I am implementing CSP in my application and the browser says CSP has been violated in the following:
1. jquery.min.js: Inline style violation in the following line

t.insertBefore(e, t.firstChild)

2. SessionExpire.js: Eval violation in the following line

setInterval("fnSessionRun()", 1000);

How can CSP be implemented properly without adding "unsafe-inline" and "unsafe-eval"?

Use a nonce. Or even better, fix the violations.

Or use  a hash.

Short sad answer: You cannot avoid the unsafe options in your CSP.
When any script you are loading is executed, it runs in the same JS context as your self written JS. Hence, it shares also the  same restrictions to used functionality.
Best you can do: Raise these issues for the library maintainers at:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues
Or even propose a fix/workaround yourself.
Alternatives:

avoid using these dependencies and find alternatives or implement the functionality yourself
consider including dependencies not via externally hosted files, but use distributed packages that would allow to bundle e.g. necessary CSS as part of your own CSS


There is no need to open the flood gates. They can use a nonce or a hash.

What about SessionExpire.js? What can I do about it?

Never heard about that. Do you have the full URL to it or even better the repo name and can tell me what for you are using it?
